# variable are not defined though code is running

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does the compiler know that "element" refers to the value of `array(prices)`?

```
let prices= ["cartoon", "what" , "sanjay"];
prices.forEach(loop);

function loop(element , what ){
    document.write( what+":"+ element + "<br>");
}
```

How does the compiler know "what" is the index of the `array(prices)`
and "element" is the value of `array(prices)`
when I have not defined `let element=prices.value()` something or `let what =price.charat()`

I was expecting an error since the "element" and "what" variable are not defined.

Comment: Because that's what the `forEach()` method does. It passes each element and index when it calls `loop`.

Comment: `element` and `what` ARE defined. They're the arguments passed to the `forEach` method, which you're calling against the `prices` array. I would look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for more information about forEach and specifically the parameters.

Comment: You can also replace `element` and `what` with your name and surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element`and `what`are the parameters of the function `loop`. This makes them *defined* inside the function. The "callback" function `loop`is called by the `Array.prototype.forEach()` method. While going through the array `prices` one by one, the method supplies each *element* and *index* of `prices` and the *array-reference* to `prices` as the three arguments to this function.

Referring to the @Oarchlight's comment under this answer:

If you want to "write" only the idex of all the elements in `prices`you can do something like below:

```js
let prices= ["cartoon", "what" , "sanjay"];
const out=document.getElementById("output")
// using .forEach:
prices.forEach(loop);

// output to page, using .map:
out.innerHTML=prices.map((_,i)=>i).join("<br>");

function loop(_,index ){
    console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

You should avoid using `document.write()` in your script as it could overwrite existing things on your page. Instead I included a `.map()` based approach for placing the `index` values on the page by setting the `innerHTML` property of the `#output` DOM element.

Comment: so how print only index and not element and other thing

Answer (score 0):

`prices.forEach(loop)` is roughly equivalent to

```
for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
  loop(prices[i], i, loop);
}
```

When you see it this way, you can see how the arguments are being passed to the function.